# Using WebInspector's Javascript Debugger, how do I break out of an infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, webkit, web-inspector

I wrote an infinite loop in my javascript code. Using WebKit's Web Inspector, how do I terminate execution? I have to quit Safari and reopen it again (after changing my code of course).

EDIT: To be more specific, I'm looking for a way to enter the looping executing process/thread to see **why** the loop isn't terminating. An analogy would be in GDB where I could do a ^C and break into the process. I'm not looking for a way to kill my web browser. I'm pretty good at that already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In using Firefox (I know the question doesn't specify Firefox, but I'm just throwing this in, in case it helps somebody), Safari, and Chrome, I found that there isn't a consistent way to break into an infinite loop, but there are ways to setup execution to break into a loop if you need to. See my test code below.

#### Firefox

Utter trash. It just stood there spinning it's rainbow. I had to kill it.

#### Safari

The nice thing about Safari is that it will eventually throw up a dialog asking if you want to stop. You should say yes. Then hit `command-option i` to bring up the Web Inspector. The source should pop-up saying that the Javascript exceeded the timeout. Hit the pause button in the right hand side towards the top, then refresh. The code will reload, now step through: I like using `command-;` because it steps through every call. If you have complex code you might never get to the end. Don't hit `continue` though (`command-/`) or you'll be back at square one.

#### Chrome

The most useful of the three. If you naively load the code, it will keep going forever. But, before loading the page, open the Web Inspector and select 'Load resources all the time'. Then reload the page. While the page is trying to load, you can click over to scripts and pause the Javascript while it is running. This is what I was looking for.

### Code

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body onload="TEST.forever.loop()">
    Nothing
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    TEST = {};
    TEST.forever = {
      loop : function() {
        var i = 0;
        while (i >= 0) {
          i++;
        }
      }
    };
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Just to add to this for Opera: open debugger (dragonfly) Ctrl-Shift-I,
then select "Sources". Navigate to the looping page, and press the " -pause button (ie like a " but bigger) then debugger stops in the loop. Use call stack in case the stop was e.g. in a jquery call inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with WebKit, but this sounds like a common  problem that I usually debug as follows: Declare an integer outside of the scope of the loop, and increment it for each iteration, then throw an exception when the iteration count exceeds the maximum expected possible amount of iterations.  So, in pseudo-code, something like the following could be used to debug this problem:

```
var iterations = 0;
var greatestPossibleNumberOfValidIterations = 500;
while(shouldLoopBooleanTest){
  iterations++;
  if(iterations>greatestPossibleNumberOfValidIterations){
     //do debugging/error handling
  }
}
```

I don't expect that this is specific enough to warrant an accepted answer, but I hope it helps you solve your problem.

Comment: But this supposes that you know where the infinite loop is. If you knew where it was, why would you let it exist?

Comment: Unfortunately this looks like the best option. If your code isn't enormous you could use this for each of your loops, though this seems like a very non-ideal solution. I also wish it was possible to force Javascript to halt wherever it is.

Comment: @javagamer, You can make it a little better by wrapping the loop logic and debugging logic, so you're api is about the same.  Also, you can throw exceptions in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using F11?  This is the key for step into: https://trac.webkit.org/wiki/WebInspector

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `top` to look at the process tree? Find the PID of the program and then type `kill -9 [PID]`.

Comment: I'll edit my question to be more specific, but this isn't the solution I'm looking for: in GDB I can 'break' into the process and then step through the infinite loop, debugging it as I go along. I'd like something similar here. Using top to kill is the same as my solution above (ie killing Safari)